# Problem with pasting

Tags: applescript

I'm trying to write an apple scrip to search Sparrow (mail client for Mac)

Here is the script:

```
 on run argv

    tell application "Sparrow"
        activate
    end tell

    tell application "System Events"
        key code 3 using {option down, command down}
        keystroke argv
    end tell
end run
```

The problem is that I want the script to take an argument on run so that I can supply it with what to search for, but I can't get it to pastet it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `argv` is always initialized to a list.
2. You cannot keystroke a list (you have to coerce each item to a string first).
3. You can never tell the exact number of parameters that will be sent to the script, so a better route would be to iterate through the list and do whatever needs to be done, as shown below:

   ```
   tell application "System Events"
       tell process "Sparrow"
           key code 3 using {command down, option down}
           repeat with this_item in argv
               keystroke (this_item as string)
           end repeat
       end tell
   end tell
   ```

---

@Runar

1. The script is implying that Sparrow is already activated.
2. You can't do this as written (the result of `every text item of argv` is still a list). However, if you coerce the result into a string, this will work, but it will squash everything together (assuming `AppleScript's text item delimiters` is `""`). If you `set AppleScript's text item delimiters to space`, then this would actually be better than the previous script...

   ```
   on run argv
       tell application "Sparrow" to activate
       tell application "System Events"
           tell process "Sparrow" --implying Sparrow is already activated
               set prevTIDs to AppleScript's text item delimiters
               key code 3 using {command down, option down}
               set AppleScript's text item delimiters to space
               keystroke (every text item of argv) as string
               set AppleScript's text item delimiters to prevTIDs
           end tell
       end tell
   end run
   ```

Comment: Ok. Your script doesn't activate sparrow, so the key code won't be sent to the right app. Could i do "keystroke (every item go agrv)?

Comment: Thanks. Looking good now. But the script need s to activate Sparrow. The point of the script is to launch it from Alfred.

Comment: thanks a lot! Works like a charm. Mad fit into an extension and credited you as the coder. Hope you don't mind.